# Transparent/blur for QMenu in QCalendarWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm trying to make transparent QMenu in QCalendarWidget. I know how to implement it in QMenuBar, but I don't know in QCalendarWidget.

It would be great if it's possible to blur the background of QMenu

I hope someone can help me.

```
self.ui.calendarWidget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
self.ui.calendarWidget.setWindowFlags(self.ui.calendarWidget.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint)
```

This is what I was trying to do.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

You can work around things by modifying QCalendarWidget grandchildren.

```
child = self.name.findChild(QWidget, 'qt_calendar_navigationbar')

grandchild = child.findChild(QHBoxLayout)
```

There you can modify margins to have space for round corners and apply `setStyleSheet`.

```
grandchild.setStyleSheet('border-radius: 10px;'
'background-color: black;')
```

Similarly you will be able to access all children to modify children widget.

To know what is what, I used the source code along with `print(self.name.children())`.